# Brute Force: Find Digits

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop

For my Intro CS class we have to create a program that finds a certain number, in this case, an address. The address falls within 1000 and 9999 and has to meet the following criteria:

- All four digits are different
- The digit in the thousands place is three times the digit in the tens place
- The number is odd
- The sum of the digits is 27

So far, I've been able to generate the range of numbers and narrow out the odd ones, but the rest is pretty confusing. Suggestions?

```
for (int i = 1000; i <= 9999; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 1)
            System.out.print(i);
        else
            System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing `System.out.println(9837);` isn't an acceptable answer?  OK, first step is to separate out the digits so you can deal with them separately.  You could either do this with `/` and `%` operators, or by converting the `int` to a `String` and looking at the characters in it.

Comment: `The digit in the thousands place is three times` means in the range of 3010-3919 or 6020-6929 or 9030-9939 - can slim processing down a lot there

Comment: see also `String.valueOf(i).toCharArray()`

Comment: Nice answers guys. More "yay I can solve a problem, let me do your homework for you" is exactly what SO needs. If you want to play code golf, [go there](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mildly optimized solution:

```
/*
All four digits are different
The digit in the thousands place is three times the digit in the tens place
The number is odd
The sum of the digits is 27
*/

// Start at 4 digit numbers, only iterate odd numbers
for (int i = 1001; i <= 9999; i += 2) {

    // break the four digits into seperate variables
    int num4 = i % 10;
    int num3 = i / 10 % 10;
    int num2 = i / 100 % 10;
    int num1 = i / 1000 % 10;

    // check that the "first" number is 3x the "third"
    if (num1 != (num3 * 3))
        continue;

    // make sure all numbers are unique
    if (num1 != num2 && num1 != num3 && num1 != num4 && num2 != num3 && num2 != num4 && num3 != num4)
        // and they sum to 27
        if ((num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) == 27)
            System.out.println(i);
}
```

The answer of course is `9837`.

Comment: Ok, this makes more sense. I was attempting on using charAt, but didn't want to use string and int in the same program. I feel stupid for asking this, but how does i += 2 determine odd values?

Comment: An odd number must end in 1,3,5,7,9. Since the loop starts at the first valid odd four-digit number (1001), it then adds two to `i` to skip over even numbers. So the next `i` is 1003, 1005, 1007 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I would use four nested `for` loops. Remember that the range of digits is `1 - 9` for the right most digit, `3 - 9` for the left most (since it is 3*10s) but `0 - 9` for the middle pair (because the number must be odd and each digit must be unique),

```
for (int a = 3; a < 10; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
        if (a == b) // unique check
            continue;
        for (int c = 1; c < 10; c++) {
            if (a == c || b == c || a != 3 * c) // unique check && # 1000s=3*10s
                continue;
            for (int d = 1; d < 10; d += 2) { // # must be odd.
                if (a == d || b == d || c == d) // unique check
                    continue;
                if (a + b + c + d == 27) { // # must sum to 27.
                    System.out.printf("%d%d%d%d%n", a, b, c, d);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output is

```
9837
```

**Edit** You can eliminate one of the loops, by calculating the identity as

```
    for (int a = 3; a < 10; a += 3) { // <-- a is a multiple of 3.
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
            if (a == b) // unique check
                continue;
            int c = a / 3; // 1000s = 3*10s
            if (b == c)
                continue;
            for (int d = 1; d < 10; d += 2) { // # must be odd.
                if (a == d || b == d || c == d) // unique check
                    continue;
                if (a + b + c + d == 27) { // # must sum to 27.
                    System.out.printf("%d%d%d%d%n", a, b, c, d);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Right: if the tens digit and the thousands digit were both 0, the sum could not be 27.

Comment: @MauricePerry - But you can use logic like that to find the entire number, without writing any code at all.  The point is to do it by brute force, not by clever thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Start by splitting each value into the four individual digits, then apply the rules:

```
for (int i = 1000; i <= 9999; i++)
{
    int ones = i % 10;
    int tens = (i / 10) % 10;
    int hundreds = (i / 100) % 10;
    int thousands = i / 1000;

    // rule 1
    if(ones != tens &&
            ones != hundreds &&
            ones != thousands &&
            tens != hundreds &&
            tens != thousands &&
            hundreds != thousands) {

        // rule 2
        if(thousands == 3 * tens) {

            // rule 3
            if(ones % 2 == 1) {

                // rule 4
                if(ones + tens + hundreds + thousands == 27) {

                    System.out.println(i);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution could be optimised (such as test for odd number first), however optimisations should only be done once the solution works (you shouldn't optimise until you have measured).